# createStore with combineReducers and applyMiddleware without second argument

Tags: javascript, redux

when using `createStore`, there are 1 argument needed and 2 optional arguments:

1. `reducer` (*Function*): A reducing function that returns the next state tree, given the current state tree and an action to handle.
2. `preloadedState` (*any*): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced `reducer` with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your `reducer` can understand.
3. `enhancer` (*Function*): The store enhancer. You may optionally specify it to enhance the store with third-party capabilities such as middleware, time travel, persistence, etc. The only store enhancer that ships with Redux is `applyMiddleware()`.

If we use `combineReducers` and `applyMiddleware()` together, it is available to omit second argument when using `createStore()`, like below:

(In [official doc's example](https://redux.js.org/api/applymiddleware#example-using-thunk-middleware-for-async-actions), same usage pattern is shown)

```js
const modules = combineReducers(reducer1, reducer2)

const store = createStore(modules, applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
```

How it is possible? `combineReducers` only returns a `function`. In the above example, can `createStore` know whether the second (and the last) parameter is the *store enhancer*, not *inisital state*?

Comment: `applyMiddleware` returns an object with `dispatch` function field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the source code of [createStore](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts) you can see the following verification code:

```
export default function createStore<
  S,
  A extends Action,
  Ext = {},
  StateExt = never
>(
  reducer: Reducer<S, A>,
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<S> | StoreEnhancer<Ext, StateExt>,
  enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<Ext, StateExt>
): Store<ExtendState<S, StateExt>, A, StateExt, Ext> & Ext {
  if (
    (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'function') ||
    (typeof enhancer === 'function' && typeof arguments[3] === 'function')
  ) {
    throw new Error(
      'It looks like you are passing several store enhancers to ' +
        'createStore(). This is not supported. Instead, compose them ' +
        'together to a single function.'
    )
  }

  if (typeof preloadedState === 'function' && typeof enhancer === 'undefined') {
    enhancer = preloadedState as StoreEnhancer<Ext, StateExt>
    preloadedState = undefined
  }

  if (typeof enhancer !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof enhancer !== 'function') {
      throw new Error('Expected the enhancer to be a function.')
    }

    return enhancer(createStore)(reducer, preloadedState as PreloadedState<
      S
    >) as Store<ExtendState<S, StateExt>, A, StateExt, Ext> & Ext
  }

  if (typeof reducer !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('Expected the reducer to be a function.')
  }
```

`preloadedState` state should be an object & the `enhancer` should be a function or else `createStore` returns an error.

Comment: **Summary**: If `enhancer` is only provided as extra arguments, then `redux` will think that the second argument(in this case `preloadedState`) is actually `enhancer` function, so take that into `enhancer` and make `preloadedState` `undefined`.